# Laravel AJAX - How to show error in console.log

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I want to show error, or to know why this code run in error:function()

Result is always run to error:function. I want to run success:function(data) and reload this page.

But console don't show anything about error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfyop.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5S4k.jpg

====== Ajax ======

```
function ex_go(r_idx)
{
    if(confirm("Are you sure?") == true)
    {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            url: "{{ route('change-centerYn') }}",
            data:{r_idx:r_idx},
            success:function(data){
                alert(data.success);
                location.reload();
            },
            error:function(xhr, data){
                console.log(xhr);
            },

    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

====== Controller ======

```
public function ex_ok(Request $request)
    {
        if(request()->ajax())
        {
            $r_idx = 'Hello';
            var_dump('<pre>', $r_idx);

            return response()->json(['msg'=>'Updated Successfully', 'success'=>true]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't using `Try` & `Catch` or error handling your controller will return 200 HTTP header status code, which means ajax will always think that process is correct and noting went wrong, try using error handling in your controller function and raise an exception if something went wrong during your code process. you can read at this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors)

you can see a sample code modification to your existing code below:

```
public function ex_ok(Request $request)
{
    try
    {
        if(request()->ajax())
        {
            $r_idx = 'Hello';
            var_dump('<pre>', $r_idx);
            return response()->json(['msg'=>'Updated Successfully', 'success'=>true]);
        }
    }
    catch(\Exception $e)
    {
        \Log::error($e); // create a log for error occurrence at storage/log/laravel.log file
        return response()->json($e->getData(), $e->getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's suddenly working! Unbelievable! 
Thank you very much! You saved my morning!

Use try catch

========= AJAX ===========

```
function ex_go(r_idx)
{
    if(confirm("해당 결제건을 지원센터로 보내시겠습니까?") == true)
    {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        console.log(r_idx);

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            url: "{{ route('change-centerYn') }}",
            data:{r_idx:r_idx},
            success:function(data){
                alert(data.success);
                location.reload();
            },
            error:function(xhr, data){
                console.log(xhr);
            }
        });
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

========= Laravel Controller =======

```
    public function ex_ok(Request $request)
    {
        try
        {
            if(request()->ajax())
            {
                $r_idx = $request->r_idx;

                $lecture = DB::table('class_order')
                ->select('*')
                ->where('r_idx', '=', $r_idx)
                ->first();

                if ($lecture->r_oid != '') {
                    $insert_data = [
                        'r_oid' => $lecture->r_oid,
                        'r_user_id' => $lecture->r_user_id,
                        'r_name' => $lecture->r_name,
                        'r_tel' => $lecture->r_tel,
                        'r_hp' => $lecture->r_hp,
                        'r_email' => $lecture->r_email,
                        'r_zip' => $lecture->r_zip,
                        'r_addr1' => $lecture->r_addr1,
                        'r_addr2' => $lecture->r_addr2,
                        'r_class' => $lecture->r_class,
                        'r_enddate' => $lecture->r_enddate,
                        'app_endday' => $lecture->app_endday,
                        'whole_study' => $lecture->whole_study,
                    ];
                    DB::table('ex_class_order')->insert($insert_data);
                    ClassOrder::where('r_idx', '=', $r_idx)->update(['centerYn' => 'y']);

                    $info_txt = "처리되었습니다.";
                }
                else
                {
                    $info_txt = "처리실패";
                }
                return response()->json(['msg'=>'Updated Successfully', 'success'=>true]);
            }
        }
        catch(\Exception $e)
        {
            \Log::error($e); // create a log for error occurrence at storage/log/laravel.log file
            return response()->json($e->getData(), $e->getStatusCode());
        }
}
```